# Issues Connecting to Impala Kerberos Hadoop - Windows/Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, kerberos, impala, sasl, impyla

I have gone through a wide search but nothing is working for me. Code goes something like this:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect
conn = connect(host = 'myhost', port = 21050, auth_mechanism = 'GSSAPI', kerberos_service_name = 'impala')

cursor = conn.cursor()

TTransportException: TTransportException(type=1, message="Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'")
```

Have tried many different versions of the following, but currently here are any possible relevant libraries:

Python 3.6.9

impyla 0.14.0

pure-sasl 0.6.2

pysasl 0.5.0

sasl 0.2.1

thrift 0.13.0

thrift-sasl 0.3.0

thriftpy 0.3.9

thriftpy2 0.4.8

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried multiple libraries on python and failed when trying to authenticate from a windows machine.There is no easy way. The Kerberos libraries mainly work on Linux. The workarounds for Windows do not work. So what can be the solution to this.
Well... be a Roman while in Rome. Try the windows native libraries from Python.

```
import sys
import clr
from System.Net.Http import *
myClienthandler = HttpClientHandler()
myClienthandler.UseDefaultCredentials = True
myClient = HttpClient(myClienthandler)
x = myClient.GetStringAsync("putyourURLwithinthequoteshere")
myresult = x.Result
print(myresult)
```

Note that the this python script will have to run by the user who has access to the URL you are trying to access. By setting `UseDefaultCredentials` property  as `True` you are passing the Kerberos tickets for the logged in user.